# extract a number and the string after it

Tags: python, regex, scripting

i have a script that parse log files and in a part of programming i have to know if a message is transmitted or not and by reading those lines i can get the Message id and know wether the message is trasmitted or not.

```
01:09:25.258 mta   Messages       I Doc O:NVS:SMTP/alarm@yyy.xx R:NVS:SMS/+654811 mid:6261
01:09:41.965 mta   Messages       I Rep 6261 OK, Message received(ID: 26)
08:14:14.469 mta   Messages       I Doc O:NVS:SMTP/alarm@xxxx.en R:NVS:SMS/+654646 mid:6262
08:14:30.630 mta   Messages       I Rep O:NVS:SMTP/alarm@azea.er R:NVS:SMS/+304859 mid:6262
08:14:30.630 mta   Messages       I Rep 6262 Error while transmitting (ID: 28)
```

---

The lines i'm interested in are the second and the last, i'd like to extract the 6261 and the ok after it and same for the last line

Comment: Is this file tab delimited? Have you attempted any code yourself? If so, please show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need regexp. Just split the lines on the whitespace.

```
>>> line.split(None, 5)
['10:56:45.255', 'Message', 'I', 'Rep', '2559', 'OK, Message received']
```

Since you only want the ID and message:

```
>>> [line.split(None, 5)[-2:] for line in file.readlines()]
[['2548', 'OK'], ['2559', 'OK, Message received'], ['2560', 'Error'], ['2561', 'Transmission... ']]
```

Note that the spaces in the message is NOT a problem.

Comment: Until a line comes along where `Message` is replaced with `A Test` or something else with spaces. Like I said in my answer, we cannot provide a full working solution without knowing the file format in more details than 4 sample lines. The `I` might also be an optional marker that is absent in other cases.

Comment: @Niels: The 5 is significant, the message can have any amount of spaces it wants. My answer works for the format given. Your claim that the I may be missing is not supported by what the OP says.

Comment: here's an update of my question, as u can see there's an mid after each message and later there's a response with that mid and a Ok or error, and i'd like to make a test to know if a message is transmitted or not, .... i allready made a function that gets the mid and the source and destination now i just have to know if a message is sent or not

Comment: @SkivlageLatif: OK, I think I see. That's not a nice format. :-) I might do it with regexps.

Comment: @LennartRegebro yeah that's right, and i have no idea how to do it :(

Comment: @SkivlageLatif: Well you are only interested in lines where the message starts with an ID, right? So make a regexp that matches only that to start with.

Comment: i edit my aswer =) i used this one and it works  re.findall(r'[Rep].(\d+).(\w+)',data)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28735/discussion-between-skivlage-latif-and-lennart-regebro)

Comment: @LennartRegebro for completion's sake - I was referring to the word `Message` not being a single word on all lines, not the actual message at the end. This would also break your solution. Point is moot however since additional edits made both our solutions 'incorrect'.

Comment: @Niels: The word Message was a single word on all lines. My solution worked with the data provided.

Answer (score -1):

`/[0-9]{4} (.*)/` would fit the purpose, but I don't know if that's generic enough for you. Depending on whether the line id (2548 etc.) can also be shorter the regexp would have to be adapted slightly, but from the 4 shown lines this would work.

When writing regular expressions the most important thing is is not to work from 'samples' alone, but also from 'usable assumptions' about the strings you are trying to match. I cannot reliably say this solution perfectly solves your problem because I don't know the entire problem, and as such cannot supply a perfect pattern.